# how to prevent a map from sorting?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, go

I have a map

```
{
"m_key": 123,
"z_key": 123,
"a_key": 123,
"f_key": 123
}
```

When i'm trying to make a json from it and print it my json becomes sorted by key and i get json:

```
{
"a_key": 123,
"f_key": 123,
"m_key": 123,
"z_key": 123
}
```

Comment: Maps are not ordered, so your initial map is just a set of key-value pairs. The `json` package orders entries by key to provide a consistent output. If it wouldn't, entries in the output would appear in random order, and only occasionally in the same order as your input. So if order matters, you have to have some data structure describing your order already, please post that. To keep that order in the output, you have to write a custom marshaler. If you don't have anything designating the order, then those 2 maps are considered identical.

Comment: You shouldn't be relying on the order of keys in a JSON object...

Answer (score -1):

To answer the original question use an ordered map

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/iancoleman/orderedmap"
)

func main() {

    o := orderedmap.New()

    // use Set instead of o["a"] = 1

    o.Set("m_key", "123") // go json.Marshall doesn't like integers
    o.Set("z_key", "123")
    o.Set("a_key", "123")
    o.Set("f_key", "123")

    // serialize to a json string using encoding/json
    prettyBytes, _ := json.Marshal(o)
    fmt.Printf("%s", prettyBytes)
}
```

But according the spec https://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.4.2
there is no guarantee that the ordering of maps is honoured, so it's probably better to use an array instead for json output

```
   // convert to array
    fmt.Printf("\n\n\n")
    arr := make([]string, 8)
    c := 0
    for _, k := range o.Keys() {
            arr[c] = k
            c++
            v, _ := o.Get(k)
            arr[c], _ = v.(string)
            c++
    }

    morePretty, _ := json.Marshal(arr)
    fmt.Printf("%s", morePretty)
```

When the array is reloaded it will be in the correct order