# JSON in response always sorted when using Go Gin

Tags: http, go, go-gin

I am writing a server by using GoLang and I am using [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) for HTTP. My issue is the JSON response is always sorted by default and I didn't see any option in Gin's documents to disable it or something like that. Does anyone know how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: Use structs if you want specific order, otherwise, with maps (g.H is a map), you'll get the behaviour based on the well documented implementation of the encoding/json package. See [link](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.18.4#Marshal): *"Map values encode as JSON objects. The map's key type must either be a string, an integer type, or implement encoding.TextMarshaler. The **map keys are sorted** and used as JSON object keys by applying the following rules, ..."*

Comment: This is same as, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469714/how-to-prevent-a-map-from-sorting, it is not gin, it is go itself.